# How to use wait() and notify()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, locks

I am  implementing a `dialog`. However I want to wait before the `dialog` is closed to return the `variable`. To do so, I tried to implement the `wait()` and `notify()` methods, but I just doesn't work. (it doesn't wait essentially).
The return Part:

```
lt = null;
            Log.d("nota_thing", "Cant find any location");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("nota_thing", "Running");
                    MapsDialog dialog = new MapsDialog();
                    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "maps_dialog");
                    Log.d("nota_thing", "Runningv2");
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        while (lt!= null) {
                            try {
                                lock.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            Log.d("nota_thing", "Second try" + lt.toString());
            return lt;
```

The dialog listener:

```
synchronized (lock) {
            lt = latLng;
            Log.d("nota_thing", "notify");
            lock.notify();
        }
```

Comment: "However I want to wait before the dialog is closed to return the variable" -- that is not possible, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare are you saying there is no way possible to implement this?! Is there any other way around my problem??

Comment: "are you saying there is no way possible to implement this?" -- correct. You cannot have a method that is run on the main application thread block while a dialog does its work. Your dialog will not even begin to be shown, because you are blocking the main application thread, and *the main application thread is needed to show a dialog*. Use a shared viewmodel, so that the dialog can emit something (on `LiveData` or an RxJava subject) and where your activity or fragment observes that result.